# obtain left and right text of a particular text using regex in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a string str='4 for 9'.The numbers in string might differ i want to obtain the left and right text of word **for** that is 4,9 I have tried it with split function .Is there any regular expression i can use to obtain this?

```
str='4 for 9'
for_exp=str.split('for')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regex,

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: regex = re.compile('([\s \S]*) for ([\s \S]*)')

In [3]: str='4 for 9'

In [4]: regex.match(str).groups()
Out[1]: ('4', '9')

In [5]: regex.match("44 for 54").groups()
Out[2]: ('44', '54')

In [6]: regex.match("44 advg for 54 2243").groups()
Out[3]: ('44 advg', '54 2243')
```

If you put a pattern in `()`, the regex will consider it as a group. So after a match is found, you can look at the various groups in the match using the `groups()` method.

It returns a tuple of size equal to the number of groups you defined in your regex.

I am matchin on `\s \S` on either side of `for`. This will match anything (all non space and space characters).
If you want onyl numbers, limit the regex to `\d+` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A string in Python is actually also a list of characters, so you can do this if there is only 1 digit

```
a = str[0]
b = str[-1]
```

if you wanna use regex, for 1 or more digits

`number = re.search('(\d+)\sfor\s(\d+)', str)`

The first element is the matched result, while `number[1]` and `number[2]` hold the start and end digit.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the numbers are only one digit.

Comment: thanks for the reminder, just updated regex to handle cases with more digits